# Copying data from one table to another different column names

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I'm having an issue copying one table's data to another. I have around 100 or so individual tables that have generally the same field names but not always. I need to be able to copy and map the fields. example: source table is BROWARD and has column names broward_ID, name, dob, address (the list goes on). The temp table I want to copy it to has ID, name, dob, address etc.

I'd like to map the fields like broward_ID = ID, name = name, etc. But many of the other tables are different in column name, so I will have to write a query for each one. Once I figure out the first on, I can do the rest. Also the column in both tables are not in order either..thanks in advance for the TSQL...

Comment: What's the question?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: For that you can use `insert into select`, but you need to create the query, as you said, if you haven't to do any transformation, then you only must consider the order of the columns

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: I've tried insert into temptable select name, address, dob where name = name and dob = dob etc etc but it erros with column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Comment: Be careful you don't have broward_ID = brevard_ID. Broward seems like data instead of metadata, anyway. One solution would be to have a column for the source table name and set a composite key on the combined table (source_table, id).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With tables:

```
BROWARD (broward_ID, name, dob, address) /*source*/
TEMP (ID, name, address,dob) /*target*/
```

If you want to copy information from BROWARD to TEMP then:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP SELECT broward_ID,NAME,ADDRESS,DOB FROM BROWARD --check that the order of columns in select represents the order in the target table
```

If you want only copy values of `broward_ID` and `name` then:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP(ID, name) SELECT broward_ID,NAME FROM BROWARD
```

Comment: What would I do if say I wanted the column in one table to correspond to another in a different table that had a different name and order? Like Such as first to firstname, DOB to date of birth etc.. .regardless of the table order.

Comment: Why does it appear you're inserting into the source table, `BROWARD`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question will resolve using update

Let's consider we have two different table

```
Table A
Id Name
1  abc
2  cde

Table B
Id Name
1  
2
```

In above case want to insert Table A Name column data into Table B Name column

```
update B inner join on B.Id = A.Id set B.Name = A.Name where ...
```