# Using TSQL to transfer data from one table to another that have different field names

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Have an issue. I have a database called DATA. Within it are multiple tables. One called MASTER and others called temp1 .

MASTER has columns called first, middle, last, dob, address, city, state, zip, phone, cell

Temp1 has essentially the same columns more or less, but in different orders, different column names, more columns than exist in MASTER, etc...

I'd like to be able to write a TSQL script that I can execute to move data from temp1 to MASTER, but map which column gets what data.

Using something like:

INSERT INTO MASTER
SELECT * from temp1

just blows up and name is in wrong field and its a mess due to the columns within temp1 which are, and in a jumbled order:

dateofbirth, lastname, firstname, middlename, telephone, cell, address, city, state, zip

What'd I'd like to do is be able to map the columns while they are transferred... like if I was using the import GUI.

so firstname to first, lastname to last, cell to cell, address to address, dateofbirth to DOB... etc. and some columns totally skipped.. but you see where its going :-)

Is this possible?? Or am I stuck using the GUI??

Comment: Here's a start: if you were just doing first and last name, it would read like this: `INSERT INTO MASTER (firstname, lastname) SELECT first, last FROM temp1`. The trick is to explicitly name each column in master, and to explicitly name each corresponding column from `temp1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying data from one table to another different column names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573468/copying-data-from-one-table-to-another-different-column-names)

Comment: This is duplicate of your own question.  You already have an accepted answer to this question.    -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the GUI does is generate SQL for you, so rest assured, this is possible.

Here's what you want:

```
INSERT INTO [MASTER] (
     first, middle, last, dob, address, city, state, zip, phone, cell, ...
)
SELECT
    firstname, middlename, lastname, dateofbirth, address, city, state, zip, telephone, cell,  ...
FROM
    [temp1]
```

SQL Server will use the indexes of the named columns to map data, disregarding names and types. If there is a type mismatch it will try to perform an implicit conversion or fail with a runtime error.

Comment: But how would it know where to drop the data if the two fields are in different order and have different names? Can you write an example using the field names I provided by chance?

Comment: @sal It uses the order of the fields in the INSERT and SELECT statement specified, not in the table definition.

Comment: but not one of the two tables are even in the same order . example the first field in master is last whereas in the other table is the cell number . all field irders are out of sync and some even get skipped over simce they are nkt needed .

Comment: @sal What part of the table names and order does not matter is not clear?  It uses the order of the INSERT and SELECT.   The INSERT and SELECT must be in sync.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a select statement with an insert statement which allows you to order which columns go where.

i.e.

```
INSERT INTO [MASTER] (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME)
SELECT FIRST,LAST FROM TEMP1
```

You can have each column list (in both the insert and the select statements) in any order - regardless of the column structure of the table.

Answer (score -1):

In my view, we need to map columns programatically or manually to insert data accurately.

I have one simple options, not sure if its best practices:

Can we generate insert statement for each row of data with proper column mappings?

**For Example:**

- Export all the rows from TEMP1 table to Excel
- Write an Insert Statement for all values of Row1 on Excel using CONCATENATE.

  ```
  =CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO MASTER(Lname,Fname,Address)  Values('",A1,"','",B1,"','",C1,"')
  ```
- Use Drag options to Generate Insert Statement for all the rows.
- Copy all the Insert Statements with values and Prepare for Inserting into Master table.